# Why do the coefficients have to be positive for one power function to "dominate"?

Tags: limits

I'm seeing this definition from a college algebra class:

*When comparing two power functions with positive coefficients, the one with the higher power dominates the one with the lower power in the long run.*

I'm failing to understand the requirement of positive coefficients. My understanding of "domination" is something like:

Consider the sum $f(x)+g(x)$ where $f(x)$ is the dominate function.
Factor out the $f(x)$ to get $f(x)(1+\frac{g(x)}{f(x)})$. As $x$ goes to infinity, $\frac{g(x)}{f(x)}$ goes to $0$ and the sum goes to just $f(x)$. This seems to work regardless of the sign of the coefficients. Am I missing something?

Comment: You are correct. I guess the teacher meant "which one will eventually be larger".

Comment: I would agree but it's still not required that both coefficients be positive. We would have a second case where f(x) has a positive coefficient while g(x) has a negative one.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose the teacher wants the students to only consider the case where the function values are positive as $x \to \infty$. You would think the teacher might be defining "dominates" as having the larger value but, if that were the case, $f(x)$ would also dominate if it's coefficient was positive and $g(x)$'s was negative. Perhaps the teacher wants the students to only consider the positive case so that there is no confusion over the definition of the word.

Answer (score 0):

A simple  counterexample is $f(x) = 1, g(x) = -x$. $g(x)$ has higher degree, but $f(x)$ dominates as $f(x) > g(x)$ for all $x > 0$.

Comment: I think I have a different definition of "dominate". "Domination is a highly informal term relating two functions. We say that one function dominates another if the magnitude of the ratio of the first function to the second increases without bound as the input increases without bound. More concisely, f(x) dominates g(x) if limx→∞g(x)/f(x)=0."